# Getting the process id for current perl script

Tags: perl

How do I get the process id for the perl process that's running the current script? getppid() doesn't return the same pid as ps -ea| grep .
 Is there is an easy way or do I just run the ps -ea command within my script and trim off the other pieces of info?

Comment: Should probably be migrated to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `$$` to get the process ID of the perl interpreter running your script:

```
iancs-imac:Documents ian$ cat test.pl 
print "$$\n";
sleep(10000);
exit()

ians-imac:Documents ian$ perl test.pl 
42291
```

In another shell:

```
iancs-imac:~ ian$ sudo ps -ef | grep perl
  501 42291 42281   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.01 perl test.pl
  501 42297 42280   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep perl
```

To learn more about about special Perl variables:

```
perldoc perlvar
```

[Or see the official online version of that information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `$$` as Ian mentions, I'm a fan of making code more readable.

To that end, Perl supports the mnemonic `$PID` if you [`use English`](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html) to enable the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up here looking to a solution to `$PID` not being defined in `BEGIN { ... }`, `POSIX::getpid()` works there.